# can't duplicate my wordpress widget

Tags: wordpress, duplicates

I want to duplicate wordpress widget i tried to change functions name and the name of the widget after install i can't see it on available widget list.

thanks for help.

The widget :  http://wordpress.org/plugins/mobile-app-showcase/

Comment: Perhaps this will help: http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy this line:

`add_action('widgets_init', 'widget_mob_show_init');`

And added it again as:

`add_action('widgets_init', 'second_widget_mob_show_init');`

Your first function name will be "widget_mob_show_init" and second is "second_widget_mob_show_init". In add_action there are two argument first is function call at time of widget initialize. and second is function name which call by that action hook.

Hope this helps.